# Jquery tilt slider with animations stopped at last slide

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, slider

I have my jquery tilt slider with animations, now its sliding auto as well,
but its not in infinite loop; which means the slider stopped at the last slide, not returning to first slide.

Can anyone help me resolving this?

```js
(function(window) {

  'use strict';
  // https://gist.github.com/edankwan/4389601
  Modernizr.addTest('csstransformspreserve3d', function() {
    var prop = Modernizr.prefixed('transformStyle');
    var val = 'preserve-3d';
    var computedStyle;
    if (!prop) return false;

    prop = prop.replace(/([A-Z])/g, function(str, m1) {
      return '-' + m1.toLowerCase();
    }).replace(/^ms-/, '-ms-');

    Modernizr.testStyles('#modernizr{' + prop + ':' + val + ';}', function(el, rule) {
      computedStyle = window.getComputedStyle ? getComputedStyle(el, null).getPropertyValue(prop) : '';
    });

    return (computedStyle === val);
  });

  var support = {
      animations: Modernizr.cssanimations,
      preserve3d: Modernizr.csstransformspreserve3d,
      transforms3d: Modernizr.csstransforms3d
    },
    isSupported = support.animations && support.preserve3d && support.transforms3d,
    animEndEventNames = {
      'WebkitAnimation': 'webkitAnimationEnd',
      'OAnimation': 'oAnimationEnd',
      'msAnimation': 'MSAnimationEnd',
      'animation': 'animationend'
    },
    // animation end event name
    animEndEventName = animEndEventNames[Modernizr.prefixed('animation')];

  function extend(a, b) {
    for (var key in b) {
      if (b.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        a[key] = b[key];
      }
    }
    return a;
  }

  function TiltSlider(el, options) {
    this.el = el;
    // available effects for the animations (animation class names) - when a item comes in / out
    this.animEffectsOut = ['moveUpOut', 'moveDownOut', 'slideUpOut', 'slideDownOut', 'slideLeftOut', 'slideRightOut'];
    this.animEffectsIn = ['moveUpIn', 'moveDownIn', 'slideUpIn', 'slideDownIn', 'slideLeftIn', 'slideRightIn'];
    // the items
    this.items = this.el.querySelector('ol.slides').children;
    // total items
    this.itemsCount = this.items.length;
    if (!this.itemsCount) return;
    // index of the current item
    this.current = 0;
    this.options = extend({}, this.options);
    extend(this.options, options);
    this._init();

  }

  TiltSlider.prototype.options = {};

  TiltSlider.prototype._init = function() {
    this._addNavigation();
    this._initEvents();
  };

  // add the navigation to the DOM
  TiltSlider.prototype._addNavigation = function() {
    // add nav "dots"
    this.nav = document.createElement('nav');
    var inner = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < this.itemsCount; ++i) {
      inner += i === 0 ? '<span class="current"></span>' : '<span></span>';
    }
    this.nav.innerHTML = inner;
    this.el.appendChild(this.nav);
    this.navDots = [].slice.call(this.nav.children);
  };

  TiltSlider.prototype._initEvents = function() {
    var self = this;
    // show a new item when clicking the navigation "dots"
    this.navDots.forEach(function(dot, idx) {
      dot.addEventListener('click', function() {
        if (idx !== self.current) {
          self._showItem(idx);
        }
      });
    });

    $(document).ready(function() {
      automatic: true;
      new TiltSlider(document.getElementById('slideshow'));
      window.setInterval(function() {
        autoplay: true,
        $('nav>.current').next().trigger('click');
        if ($('nav > .current').next().index() === '-1') {
          $('nav > .span').trigger('click');

        }
      }, 1500);


    });


  };



  TiltSlider.prototype._showItem = function(pos) {
    if (this.isAnimating) {
      return false;
    }
    this.isAnimating = true;

    classie.removeClass(this.navDots[this.current], 'current');

    var self = this,
      // the current item
      currentItem = this.items[this.current];

    this.current = pos;

    // next item to come in
    var nextItem = this.items[this.current],
      // set random effects for the items
      outEffect = this.animEffectsOut[Math.floor(Math.random() * this.animEffectsOut.length)],
      inEffect = this.animEffectsIn[Math.floor(Math.random() * this.animEffectsOut.length)];

    currentItem.setAttribute('data-effect-out', outEffect);
    nextItem.setAttribute('data-effect-in', inEffect);

    classie.addClass(this.navDots[this.current], 'current');

    var cntAnims = 0,
      // the number of elements that actually animate inside the current item
      animElemsCurrentCount = currentItem.querySelector('.tiltview').children.length,
      // the number of elements that actually animate inside the next item
      animElemsNextCount = nextItem.querySelector('.tiltview').children.length,
      // keep track of the number of animations that are terminated
      animEndCurrentCnt = 0,
      animEndNextCnt = 0,
      // check function for the end of each animation
      isFinished = function() {
        ++cntAnims;
        if (cntAnims === 2) {
          self.isAnimating = false;
        }
      },
      // function for the end of the current item animation
      onEndAnimationCurrentItem = function() {
        ++animEndCurrentCnt;
        var endFn = function() {
          classie.removeClass(currentItem, 'hide');
          classie.removeClass(currentItem, 'current');
          isFinished();
        };

        if (!isSupported) {
          endFn();
        } else if (animEndCurrentCnt === animElemsCurrentCount) {
          currentItem.removeEventListener(animEndEventName, onEndAnimationCurrentItem);
          endFn();
        }
      },
      // function for the end of the next item animation
      onEndAnimationNextItem = function() {
        ++animEndNextCnt;
        var endFn = function() {
          classie.removeClass(nextItem, 'show');
          classie.addClass(nextItem, 'current');
          isFinished();
        };

        if (!isSupported) {
          endFn();
        } else if (animEndNextCnt === animElemsNextCount) {
          nextItem.removeEventListener(animEndEventName, onEndAnimationNextItem);
          endFn();
        }
      };

    classie.addClass(currentItem, 'hide');
    classie.addClass(nextItem, 'show');

    if (isSupported) {
      currentItem.addEventListener(animEndEventName, onEndAnimationCurrentItem);
      nextItem.addEventListener(animEndEventName, onEndAnimationNextItem);
    } else {
      onEndAnimationCurrentItem();
      onEndAnimationNextItem();
    }
  };

  // add to global namespace
  window.TiltSlider = TiltSlider;

})(window);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to trigger click on the first span when `$('nav > .current').next().index() === '-1'`.

```
$(document).ready(function(){ automatic:true;
    new TiltSlider( document.getElementById( 'slideshow' ) );               
    window.setInterval(function(){  autoplay:true,          

        if($('nav > .current').next().index() === '-1'){
            $('nav > .span').eq(0).trigger('click');
        }else{
          $('nav>.current').next().trigger('click');
          }               
    } , 1500);

 });
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. i tried i have got error and didnt worked.

Comment: using if after autoplay:true, gives me an error as if can be used only after an operand.